# Why this code leads to an alphabetical column list in excel?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
table = pd.pivot_table(gains,
                       index=['Account', 'Date', 'Security'],
                       values=['Units', 'Proceeds', 'ACB', 'Gain(Loss)'])

# pivot table for gains(losses) broken down by investment account

for account in table.index.get_level_values(0).unique():
    # print gains losses sheets one summary for each investment account
    temp_df = table.xs(account, level=0)
    # column_titles = ['Units', 'Proceeds', 'ACB', 'Gain(Loss)']
    # temp_df.reindex(columns=column_titles)
    s_name = account + ' - ' + str(idate.year)
    temp_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=s_name,
                     columns=['Units', 'Proceeds', 'ACB', 'Gain(Loss)'])
```

The first excel sheet shows the proper order of columns for the gains dataframe:

i.e. Account Date Security Units Proceeds ACB Gain(Loss)

But the individual temp.df dataframes create excel sheets with the following column order:

i.e. Date Security ACB Gain(Loss) Proceeds Units

Note that after the Date and Security columns the columns are in alphabetical order even though I have the columns=[] parameter in my code. This seemed to be working properly for a while and suddenly reverted to alphabetical order for "Units Proceeds ACB and Gain(Loss)"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: The order in the dataframe is "Account Date Security Units Proceeds ACB Gain(Loss)" but the to_excel procedure seems alphabetize from "Units" onward for the individual sheets.

Edit2: Alternatively, what is the best way to get these columns in the order that I want. Should I be using openpyxl, xlrd, xlwt or is what I want not really possible?

Comment: Apparently, `columns=[]` selects the columns to write, but does not define the order. Perhaps you should reorder the columns in the DataFrame before exporting.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the following:

```
s_name = account + ' - ' + str(idate.year)
            temp_df = temp_df[['Units', 'Proceeds', 'ACB', 'Gain(Loss)']]
            temp_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=s_name,
                             columns=['Units', 'Proceeds', 'ACB', 'Gain(Loss)'])
```